# Set Implicit Transaction ON on Management Studio for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio I check the option Tools/Options/Query Execution/SQL Server/ANSI/SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS

This works for SQL Server database but It seems not works if I connect to Azure SQL Database

How can set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to ON by default for Azure SQL Database?

Edit

I tried this:

from Object Explorer I select the database, right click, new Query and execute this script:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (a INT)
ROLLBACK
SELECT * FROM T1
```

The result is as expected: Invalid object name 'T1'

Now i click on "Change connection" button

I reconnect to the same Azure SQL Server instance

I select the same Database from the database combo list and execute the same script.

Now the error is "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION."

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue. First I tested that SQL Server and SQL Azure behave both the same for implicit transactions with the following script.

```
-- Transact-SQL.  

go  

-- Preparations.  

SET NOCOUNT ON;  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;  

go  

WHILE (@@TranCount > 0) COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

go  

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.t1',N'U') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE dbo.t1;  

go  

CREATE table dbo.t1 (a int);  

go  



PRINT N'-------- [Test A] ---- OFF ----';  

PRINT N'[A.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF.';  

PRINT N'[A.02] @@TranCount, at start, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;  

go  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (11);  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (12);  

PRINT N'[A.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  



PRINT N' ';  

PRINT N'-------- [Test B] ---- ON ----';  

PRINT N'[B.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.';  

PRINT N'[B.02] @@TranCount, at start, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;  

go  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (21);  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (22);  

PRINT N'[B.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

PRINT N'[B.04] @@TranCount, after COMMIT, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  



PRINT N' ';  

PRINT N'-------- [Test C] ---- ON, then BEGIN TRAN ----';  

PRINT N'[C.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.';  

PRINT N'[C.02] @@TranCount, at start, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;  

go  

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (31);  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (32);  

PRINT N'[C.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

PRINT N'[C.04] @@TranCount, after a COMMIT, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

PRINT N'[C.05] @@TranCount, after another COMMIT, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  



PRINT N' ';  

PRINT N'-------- [Test D] ---- ON, INSERT, BEGIN TRAN, INSERT ----';  

PRINT N'[D.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.';  

PRINT N'[D.02] @@TranCount, at start, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;  

go  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (41);  

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 VALUES (42);  

PRINT N'[D.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

PRINT N'[D.04] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

PRINT N'[D.05] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10));  

go  



-- Clean up.  

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;  

go  

WHILE (@@TranCount > 0) COMMIT TRANSACTION;  

go  

DROP TABLE dbo.t1;  

go
```

The following results were the same on both SQL Server and Azure SQL Database (DTU model).

```
-------- [Test A] ---- OFF ----
[A.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF.
[A.02] @@TranCount, at start, == 0
[A.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 0

-------- [Test B] ---- ON ----
[B.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.
[B.02] @@TranCount, at start, == 0
[B.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 1
[B.04] @@TranCount, after COMMIT, == 0

-------- [Test C] ---- ON, then BEGIN TRAN ----
[C.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.
[C.02] @@TranCount, at start, == 0
[C.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 2
[C.04] @@TranCount, after a COMMIT, == 1
[C.05] @@TranCount, after another COMMIT, == 0

-------- [Test D] ---- ON, INSERT, BEGIN TRAN, INSERT ----
[D.01] Now, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.
[D.02] @@TranCount, at start, == 0
[D.03] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 2
[D.04] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 1
[D.05] @@TranCount, after INSERTs, == 0
```

Then I configured implicit transactions as default on SSMS, commented the SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS statements, and on Tests B, C and D, I received the same results.

I tested this with SSMS 17.8.1. Which version of SSMS you are using? Please download the latest version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I updated SSMS to latest version. See my edit in original post

Comment: Could you please run test B, C, D that I provided but before you run those tests, comment all SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS that you find on those 3 tests. You should have same results as me.

Comment: If I right-click on the database in solution explorer, select New Query and I run your test I got the same result as you. After this I click on "Change connection" icon, using the same sql server instance, I select the same Database from the list and run your script again I got "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION." after B.03, C.04, D.04

Comment: I you received the same results as me that means Azure SQL Database does not behave differently that SQL Server (in my computer SQL 2019). Your assumption was not correct about Azure SQL. If you can create a script that can prove SQL Azure behaves different than SQL when using SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS in  SSMS please share with us, meanwhile the script I provided proof otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the document: [SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS { ON | OFF }
```

My SQL server version is 12.0, I tested in SSMS 17.9 and 18.1, run the SQL in `Mydatabase`:

[image]

**Update:**

Set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS:
[image]

But from the document [Set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it says:

- Implicit transactions may unexpectedly be ON due to ANSI defaults.
  For details see [SET ANSI_DEFAULTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-defaults-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

  IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON is not popular. In most cases where
  IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON, it is because the choice of SET
  ANSI_DEFAULTS ON has been made.

I open the new query and  `SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON`, it still worked:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio has an option to SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTION ON by default (Tools/Options/Query Execution/SQL Server/ANSI/SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS) so when you open a new query editor this is automatically set and you don't need to write SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON. This is the option that doesn't work with Azure database.

Comment: @skysurfer Thanks. I test again and updated my answer, it still works.

Comment: @skysurfer, very strange! I tried disconnect/reconnect the SQL database, even tried restart the SSMS, run the same query, the result always be `Invalid object name 'T1'.` .